# append number to variable name and call it in a loop (php) (smarty)

Tags: php, variables, loops, smarty, append

I have a simple question. I need to append 1,2,3 etc to a variable name in smarty. The variables are `$user1`, `$user2`, `$user3` etc. I use smarty to do a simple loop like this:

```
     {section name=user_info start=1 loop=$users}
       <tr>
        <td> User{$smarty.section.user_info.index} </td> // prints user1, user2, user3 etc

        <td>
         {$user} append this: {$smarty.section.user_info.index} // need to call $userX
        </td>

      </tr> 
    {/section}
```

I tried everything on the [variable info site to smarty](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.syntax.variables.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `$user` a numerically index array instead of declaring a variable for each user as you have now ($user1, $user2, $user3) and then you can use:

> `{$foo.$bar}`    <-- display variable
>   key value of an array, similar to PHP
>   `$foo[$bar]`

According to [Smarty Variables manual](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.syntax.variables.php)

Once converted this would be like:

```
$user = array(
    0 => $user0,
    1 => $user1,
);
```

So in your case it would be `{$user.$smarty.section.user_info.index}`.